# How can I reclaim memory used by mgcv?

Tags: r, memory, gam, mgcv

I am having an issue where I run out of memory when running a large number of GAM fits using R package mgcv. I load the library and initialize some random data with the following script.

```
library(mgcv) #for gam
set.seed(1)
n = 1000
myData = data.frame(X1=rnorm(n),
                X2=rnorm(n),
                X3=rnorm(n),
                Y=rnorm(n))
gc()
```

This gives

```
          used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
Ncells 1134579 60.6    1476915 78.9  1368491 73.1
Vcells 1611179 12.3    2518261 19.3  1961928 15.0
```

next I fit ten GAMs and check memory usage with

```
fits <- lapply(1:10, function(j) {gam(Y~te(X1,X2,k=10)+te(X2,X3,k=10), data=myData)})
gc()
object.size(fits)
```

the result is

```
           used (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb) max used  (Mb)
Ncells  1200064 64.1    1835812  98.1  1368491  73.1
Vcells 10192307 77.8   15351293 117.2 14537510 111.0
> object.size(fits)
22871928 bytes
```

Notice that I have created only one object (fits) but memory usage is triple the size of this object. Eventually R runs out of memory entirely as I fit more models. What I have been doing is saving to disk

```
saveRDS(fits, "fits", refhook=function(...) {"dummy"})
```

then starting a new session and reloading

```
library(mgcv) #for gam
fits <- readRDS("fits", refhook=function(...) {.GlobalEnv})
gc()
```

and voila! the memory is back

```
          used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
Ncells 1139845 60.9    1835812 98.1  1368491 73.1
Vcells 4322985 33.0    4972379 38.0  4324092 33.0
```

Is there any way to re-claim the memory without needing to save to disk, start a new session, and then load from disk?

Comment: Is the problem that `lapply()` craps out with a can't allocate more memory error before returning? Have you tried running this as a `for` loop instead? When I was doing this sort of thing with `mgcv::gam()`, I used a `for` loop, assigned the `i`th model to object `foo` so it was overwritten each iteration, wrote each model out to disk during the iteration, and cycled through 20+GB of models  that way. Assuming you use a consistent naming convention for the `.rds` files you can then write a script which loads each model in turn and does with it/extracts what you want.